# property of induced map from equivalence relations

Tags: algebraic-topology

This problem is from Chapter 1 of Rotman's Algebraic topology book.

## Problem

[image]

I solved the first part, but only have a partial proof of $f$ is identification $\Rightarrow$ $\overline f$ is an indication.

Here's Rotman's definition of *identification*:
[image]

## Partial Proof

I will use the notation $\tau_X$ to denote the topology of $X$. Let $\pi$ be the natural map from $X \rightarrow X/ \sim$, let $\sigma$ be the natural map from $ Y \rightarrow Y / \square $. Then

$$ \overline f = \sigma f \pi^{-1} $$ and

\begin{align}
V \in \tau_{Y/ \square} & \iff \sigma^{-1}(V) \in \tau_Y \\
& \iff f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V) \in \tau_x \\
& \Longrightarrow  \pi f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V) = (\overline{f})^{-1}(V) \in \tau_{X/ \sim}
\end{align}

($\sigma$ is an identification, $f$ is an identification and $\overline f$ is continuous).

Because $\pi$ is an identification,

$$ \pi f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V)  \in \tau_{X / \sim} \Longrightarrow \pi^{-1} \pi f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X$$

## What I can't figure out

So it remains to show that $\pi^{-1} \pi f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \sigma^{-1}(V)$. "$\supset$" is obvious, but the reverse inclusion is not.

## Update

Rotman's warning:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean "$f$ is a quotient mapping" when you say it is an 'identification'?

Comment: @FShrike See my addition to the Problem section -- I wasn't familiar with this usage of *identification* either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
\begin{align}
V \in \tau_{Y/\square} 
& \iff \sigma^{-1}(V) \in \tau_Y \quad (\textrm{$\sigma$ is an identification}) \\
& \iff f^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(V)) \in \tau_X \quad (\color{red}{\rm if} \textrm{$f$ is an identification}) \\
& \iff (\sigma f)^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X \\
& \iff (\overline f \pi)^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X \quad (\textrm{since $\sigma f = \overline f \pi$}) \\
& \iff \pi^{-1}(\overline f{}^{-1}(V)) \in \tau_X \\
& \iff \overline f{}^{-1}(V) \in \tau_{X/{\sim}} \quad (\textrm{$\pi$ is an identification})
\end{align}

Comment: $\sigma f = \sigma f \pi^{-1} \pi$ because $\sigma f$ is constant on fibers of $\pi$?

Comment: @IsaacR24 I don’t understand your question. Where did I write that? The equality $\sigma f = \overline f \pi$ is **by definition of** $\overline f$, and the other equalities are just properties of the inverse image under a function.

Comment: Can you explain why it's by definition? I believe the definition is $\overline f = \sigma f \pi^{-1}$

Comment: @IsaacR24 First, $\pi$ is not invertible, so it makes no sense to write $\pi^{-1}$.
Second, $\overline f$ is by definition the map that takes the $\sim$-class of $x \in X$ to the $\square$-class of $f(x)$, that is $\overline f(\pi(x)) = \sigma(f(x))$ for every $x \in X$, i.e. $\overline f \pi = \sigma f$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the patient explanation! Rotman didn't explicit say what the induced map was, but now I see why this must be the definition. Everything is clear now.